# Roslyn Scripting - Script without "System"

Tags: c#, scripting, visual-studio-2015, roslyn

As of [this](http://daveaglick.com/posts/compiler-platform-scripting) article I want to write a little C# scripting engine to work. I have tried this code:

```
System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader("example.txt");
var prog = sr.ReadToEnd();
sr.Close();
ScriptOptions so = ScriptOptions.Default;
Console.WriteLine(CSharpScript.RunAsync(prog, so).Result.GetVariable("sum").Value);
Console.ReadKey();
```

And the file content of example.txt is:

```
System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader("foo.txt");
string s = sr.ReadToEnd();
int sum = System.Convert.ToInt32(s);
```

Now I want to restrict the user to only basic functions of C# (using int, string, while, for) and some self defined functions but NOT the whole .NET library. But even if I don't include System.IO als reference the user can type System.IO.something and will get the right thing.

Is there a possibility to **remove the access to "System" from the script**?

I'm glad with any answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "**remove the access to "System" from the script**"?

Comment: There should not be any possibility to use any element of System. E.g. the user who writes the script should not be possible to use System.IO.StreamReader, System.Convert or System.Threading.Thread at all.

Comment: Do you want to achieve sandboxing, or disable the usage of anything in the `System` namespace? The latter one could be achieved by analyzing your input code, and checking the namespace of each symbol. The former can be done by loading the code into a separate app domain, and specifying the permissions of the app domain.

Comment: I want to build something like a scripting API, where the user is provided some methods by the C# app e.g. to wrap file access. I want for example be sure that a file can only written to a certain folder and subfolders of it. Therefore I want to restrict the user to use System.IO etc. but use my predefined methods which check that before they execute the request.
The AppDomain approach seems pretty good to me. But how can I provide these methods without restricing them, too? Can I call back the original application from the new AppDomain to restrict only the user code but not my API-methods?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to set up the `ScriptingOptions` properly, meaning that a custom `MetadataReferenceResolver` needs to be used instead of the default one, which is resolving the missing references automatically. I don't know if there is already a resolver that only resolves assemblies based on its parameters, but you can certainly implement yours. Check out the [`TestMetadataReferenceResolver`](http://source.roslyn.io/#Roslyn.Test.Utilities/TestMetadataReferenceResolver.cs,5c64995f78e064a5), which does something similar.

**Update**
This won't work for things that are defined in mscorlib.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I implemented my own ScriptOptions and RuntimeMetadataReferenceResolver classes (by removing the seal keyword from the original classes and inheriting from them) and made the ResolveReference method to return an empty ImmutableArray. Unfortunatelly, my solution acts exactly like the original ScriptOptions. Is there another point where I have to change something?

Comment: Could you provide us the code to check it? Also, I just came across a comment on top of [`ResolveMissingAssemblies`](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/MetadataReference/MetadataReferenceResolver.cs,cfee6ff1c43f8166) saying that it only affects loading of assemblies explicitly not referenced by the compilation. It would be worth checking out what those assemblies are.

Comment: I checked the script object, and it has by default a reference to mscorlib. So coming back to your original problem, you'd probably need to create your own compilation from the code and load that into its own appdomain. Check out this (little outdated) [proof of concept](http://www.filipekberg.se/2011/12/08/hosted-execution-of-smaller-code-snippets-with-roslyn/) for sandboxing the input source code. And then you can specify `IsolatedStorageFilePermission` to allowed usage of a private virtual file system.

Comment: @Tamas, it's been a while since you posted that outdated proof of concept, but just wanted to record for anyone looking at this going forward is that the concept does not work in newer .NET versions due to Microsoft deprecating SecurityPermission.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.permissions.securitypermission?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0